# Couchbase point in time recovery?

Tags: backup, couchbase, restore, couchbase-bucket

Is it possible to restore couchbase cluster or node point in time?  if any please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: This feature is in our roadmap already, but currently you have to use our standard backup tools

Comment: Okay, It means we should rely on last backup till now. Thanks.

Comment: I believe there are some 3rd party solutions that some Couchbase users employ

Comment: When we can expect this feature? From backup we can restore till last backup only.